# How to get value of variables in Scala, where name of variable is obtained as string

Tags: scala

i have existing variables:

```
scala> a
res69: Double = 5.0

scala> b
res70: Double = 10.0

scala> c
res71: Double = 15.0
```

There is a list containing variable names as string like:

```
scala> val variableList = List("a","b","c")
variableList: List[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

How to get values of variables in this list. I am expecting output as:

```
List(5.0, 10.0, 15.0)
```

Comment: have you looked at Java/Scala reflection capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the scope of question is limited to getting values of terms defined in scala REPL, following works:

```
> val a = 5.0
> val b = 10.0
> val c = 15.0
> val variableList = List("a", "b", "c")
> variableList.map(v => $intp.valueOfTerm(v).getOrElse("Undefined: " + v))
// List[AnyRef] = List(5.0, 10.0, 15.0)
```

$intp is the REPL's interpreter.IMain object.

Comment: Is there a way to do it, while running as an application?